# How to attach 2 css variables to an JSX element in React & Emotion

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, emotion

How can I attach both style1 & style2 to the div below using the Emotion library?

```
const style1 = css`
  display: flex;
`

const style2 = css`
   width: 0;
`

const el= () => (
    <div css={style1}>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Emotion you can do what's called [composition](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition):

```js
const style1 = css`
  display: flex;
`

const style2 = css`
   width: 0;
`

const el= () => (
    <div 
        css={css`
            ${style1};
            ${style2};
        `}
    >
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution can be simplified as follows:

```
const el= () => (
    <div css={[style1, style2]}>
)
```

This type of composition for CSS objects is also in the documentation (but not easy to find): https://emotion.sh/docs/best-practices#method-1-export-css-objects

```
const style1 = css({
  display: flex;
})

const style2 = css({
  width: 0;
})

const combinedStyles = css([style1, style2])

const el= () => (
    <div css={combinedStyles}>
)
```